# Binary files: ios::binary not working

Tags: c++, binary

I'm trying to write a string in binary.

Here is my code:

```
bool Database::createTable(string name, string content)
{
    string *filePath = new string(*this->path + "/" + name + ".dt");

    ifstream *checkFile = new ifstream(*filePath);

    if(checkFile->good())
    {
        return false;
    }

    ofstream *file = new ofstream(*filePath, ios::binary);

    file->write(content.c_str(), content.size());

    file->close();

    delete filePath;
    delete checkFile;
    delete file;

    return true;
}
```

I would like to see something like that in a text editor:

```
6a6f 686e 0000 0000 0000 0000 1500 0000
1039 4099 b67f 0000 1c39 4099 b67f 0000
```

But I'm seeing plain text.

If I take out the `ios::binary`, it outputs the same thing.

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstand the meaning of _binary file mode_. See: [Difference between opening a file in binary vs text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863959/difference-between-opening-a-file-in-binary-vs-text). In addition, there's no good reason to use `new` in this code (C++ is not Java).

Comment: Off topic but is there any particular reason you're using pointers and `new` instead of the objects themselves?

Comment: @0x499602D2 what's the problem using it? Don't want to store everything on stack.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get such a format, use an *hexdump* tool. From C++:

[How would I create a hex dump utility in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804251)